# Display null values last on initial sorting a JQuery DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have web page where I'm displaying data that has a date column that is derived from the application and not from the database. The initial sort aaSorting is exactly what I needed as users want the data to be sorted by this date when visiting the page for the 1st time. However the null values are displayed at the very beginning of the list when in my case I want them at the end of the list. Is there a setting than I can use to do this?

This jsfiddle demonstrates the problem I'm having.
https://jsfiddle.net/k4pmL8j0/4/

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
    "sScrollY": "460px",
    "sScrollX": "1050px",
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bSortable": true,
    "aaSorting": [[4,'asc']],
    "oLanguage": {"sZeroRecords": "", "sEmptyTable": ""}
    });
} );
```

Comment: You could add a `data-order` attribute to the `td`.

Comment: Just so you know, you're sorting your date column incorrectly. You are in fact sorting it first by the `day` then the `month` and then finally the `year`. That's the complete opposite way to sort it.

Comment: Fixed the jsfiddle so the relevant column is declared as a date instead of a String.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it to work thanks to the fine folks at datatables.net. I ended up having to override the default behavior which returns -Infinity if the date can't be parsed.

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.type.order['date-pre'] = function ( d ) {
    return Date.parse( d ) || Infinity;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could make use of the `data-order` attribute so you can control how the table is sorted by that column.

For regular dates just do something like:

```
<td data-order="2016-09-06">06-Sep-2016</td>
```

For empty dates use something like `z`:

```
<td data-order="z"></td>
```

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hjckpers/)

#### Note

This is a nice approach because you can format the dates that get displayed any way you want. You're not restricted to using the `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Answer (score 0):

this may helps you because it consider `date` as `String`:

so if you notice the data, you get `date` sorted as `String`, like i set now `aaSorting": [[4,'desc']]`, so it sorted like:

- if you see first letter of each date, it sort like 2...1...0...null same for 2nd , and all character sorting.

you can chnage `aaSorting` attribute value to this `aaSorting": [[4,'desc']]`, then it is working , i have updated it.

**use `aaSorting": [[4,'desc']]` instead of `aaSorting": [[4,'asc']]`**

[Jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/k4pmL8j0/2/)

==========================================================
 
if you want to convert `String` to `Date` in your tabledate then use `data-order` attribute, it will now works as `Date` and sort data as `Date`too.

as said by @patrick, which sort data as datatype `date` too, but as mentioned in your questioned, it's `string`

 if you have any doubt, you can comment below.

Comment: I think something got lost in the translation when I made that jsfiddle, the column is a Date and not a String. Thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Comment: @rmaitipe , you're welcome!, if it is helpful to you, you can accept it. , if you  have another question, you can send link, i'll surely help you

Comment: If you sort your date column you'll notice that the dates aren't actually sorted properly. Yes you have the null dates at the bottom but the others don't make sense.