# Empty spaces are displaying at top of Datatable after sorting in ascending, but need to display at bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatable

In datatable while sorting in descending order empty cells are coming at last but while sorting in ascending order empty spaces are displaying top of datatable, I need to display those empty spaces at bottom of the table even after sorting in both ascending and descending.

```js
$('#idealistTable').DataTable({
  "paging": false,
  "searching": false,
  "ordering": true,
  "info": false,
  "order": [
    [4, "desc"]
  ]
});
```

Comment: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/26301/custom-sorting-disabling-sorting-per-column

Comment: Look at [Display null values last on initial sorting a JQuery DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39355390/12567365), or at [Sorting Empty values always to top in Datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53725850/12567365) or at various [similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=datatables+sort+blanks+to+end+site:stackoverflow.com).